# Is $X^6$ prime element in $Z[X^2,X^3]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Is $X^6$ prime element in $Z[X^2,X^3]$?

$X^6=(X^2)^3$ so $X^6$ is not irreducible element and then $X^6$ is not prime element.

However I am not sure if my reasoning is correct because in the definition of irreductible element is: "such an irreversible element of a ring which cannot be represented as the product of two irreversible elements". But I do not understand what elements are irreversible in my ring and wish someone would explain it to me and tell me if my reasoning is correct.

Comment: You are correct. In an integral domain, a prime element must be an irreducible element. Contrapositively, if you find an element that is not irreducible, it cannot be prime. Certainly, $X^6$ is not irreducible because it is expressible as $(X^2)^3$ and $(X^3)^2.$

Comment: Alternatively, $X^6$ is not prime since it divides the product $(X^3)(X^3)$, but does not divide $X^3$; that is, it divides a product in which it does not divide either factor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A unit in a commutative ring is an element $a$ such that there exists an element $b$ with $ab=1$. What you call "irreversible" elements, is usually referred to as a non-unit, that is, an element that is not a unit.

In $\mathbb Z[X]$ we have a notion of degree that satisfies $\deg(fg)=\deg(f)+\deg(g)$. In particular, since $\deg(1)=0$, in order for $fg=1$ to be true we must have $\deg(f)=\deg(g)=0$. Hence, the only units in $\mathbb Z[X]$ are the units in $\mathbb Z$, which are exactly $+1$ and $-1$.

The same is then of course true for the subring $\mathbb Z[X^2,X^3]$. Every element different from $\pm 1$ is a non-unit (irreversible).

Hence, $X^6 = (X^2)(X^2)(X^2)$ is indeed a decomposition of $X^6$ into irreversibles, so that $X^6$ is not irreducible and hence not prime.

Comment: Why the down vote?